# Any similar *native* alternative to Sparx Systems' Enterprise Architect on OS X?

Tags: osx, uml

I am a fan of Sparx Systems' [Enterprise Architect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Architect_%28software%29) on Windows. Is there any alternative to it that is similar in terms of supported features (e.g. full UML support, nice looking graphs, smooth import/export, fast operation, not an Eclipse-based plugin) and overall approach and is *native* to OS X. (I don't want to go down the [virtualization](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/sysreq.html) route with CodeWeaver Crossover, etc. A commercial product would be fine.)

Comment: Which particular features of EA are you looking for, are cross platform tools suitable, are web based tools suitable?Are you willing to pay for it? Please expand your question as then you are more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: Crossover/CodeWeaver isn't virtualisation, it's a compatibility layer. The performance of Sparx Enterprise Architect on Mac is fine.